# how to check the value in some columns and add the header to the new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

my `df` input data in pandas look like that:

```
CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  P1-25   P1-93   P1-88   P1-6    P1-89   P1-26   P1-12   P1-92   P1-22   P1-90   P1-28   P1-95
NC_064017.1 965007  .   A   G   .   .   .   GT  0/0 1/1 .   0/1 1/1 .   0/0 1/1 0/0 0/1 .   0/1
NC_064017.1 965038  .   C   T   .   .   .   GT  0/0 1/1 0/0 0/1 1/1 .   0/0 1/1 0/0 0/1 0/0 0/1
NC_064017.1 1250643 .   T   C   .   .   .   GT  0/1 0/1 0/1 1/1 0/1 1/1 0/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1
NC_064017.1 1250740 .   T   A   .   .   .   GT  0/1 1/1 0/1 1/1 0/1 1/1 0/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/1
```

I want to check for all rows if in columns from `P1-25` to `P1-95` is value '1/1' --> if True, add the column header to the first new column `1/1`; and if the value is '0/0' --> add the column header to the second new column `0/0` to create lists of samples with '1/1' in one column and '0/0' in the second one.

My expected output should look like that:

```
CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  P1-25   P1-93   P1-88   P1-6    P1-89   P1-26   P1-12   P1-92   P1-22   P1-90   P1-28   P1-95   1/1  0/0
NC_064017.1 965007  .   A   G   .   .   .   GT  0/0 1/1 .   0/1 1/1 .   0/0 1/1 0/0 0/1 .   0/1 P1-93,P1-89,P1-92   P1-25,P1-12,P1-22
NC_064017.1 965038  .   C   T   .   .   .   GT  0/0 1/1 0/0 0/1 1/1 .   0/0 1/1 0/0 0/1 0/0 0/1 P1-93,P1-89,P1-92   P1-25,P1-88,P1-12,P1-22,P1-28
NC_064017.1 1250643.    T   C   .   .   .   GT  0/1 0/1 0/1 1/1 0/1 1/1 0/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1 P1-6,P1-26,P1-95    P1-22,P1-90,P1-28
NC_064017.1 1250740.    T   A   .   .   .   GT  0/1 1/1 0/1 1/1 0/1 1/1 0/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/1 P1-93,P1-6,P1-26    P1-22,P1-90,P1-28
```

I've tried to do it with `apply` function but I don't know how to use it for two conditions. I would like to avoid iteration with `for` loop because my data is huge (almost million rows).

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dot product to create expected strings:

```
cols = df.filter(like='P1-').columns
sep = ','
df['1/1'] = pd.Series(df[cols].eq('1/1').dot((cols + sep))).str.rstrip(sep)
df['0/0'] = pd.Series(df[cols].eq('0/0').dot((cols + sep))).str.rstrip(sep)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         CHROM      POS ID REF ALT QUAL FILTER INFO FORMAT P1-25 P1-93 P1-88 P1-6 P1-89 P1-26 P1-12 P1-92 P1-22 P1-90 P1-28 P1-95                1/1                            0/0
0  NC_064017.1   965007  .   A   G    .      .    .     GT   0/0   1/1     .  0/1   1/1     .   0/0   1/1   0/0   0/1     .   0/1  P1-93,P1-89,P1-92              P1-25,P1-12,P1-22
1  NC_064017.1   965038  .   C   T    .      .    .     GT   0/0   1/1   0/0  0/1   1/1     .   0/0   1/1   0/0   0/1   0/0   0/1  P1-93,P1-89,P1-92  P1-25,P1-88,P1-12,P1-22,P1-28
2  NC_064017.1  1250643  .   T   C    .      .    .     GT   0/1   0/1   0/1  1/1   0/1   1/1   0/1   0/1   0/0   0/0   0/0   1/1   P1-6,P1-26,P1-95              P1-22,P1-90,P1-28
3  NC_064017.1  1250740  .   T   A    .      .    .     GT   0/1   1/1   0/1  1/1   0/1   1/1   0/1   0/1   0/0   0/0   0/0   0/1   P1-93,P1-6,P1-26              P1-22,P1-90,P1-28
```